# Saving output from several job arrays in one single file

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#$ -q cluster
#$ -cwd
#$ -N blast
#$ -e /path/to/log
#$ -o /path/to/log
#$ -l job_mem=8G
#$ -pe serial 4
#$ -t 1-605:1 -tc 20

BLAST='/path/to/blast'
REFERENCE="/path/to/reference.fasta"
INDIR="/path/to/fastafiles"
OUTDIR="/path/to/outdir"

 $BLAST/blastn -outfmt 6 -query $INDIR/$SGE_TASK_ID.fasta -db $REFERENCE -out $OUTDIR/single_output_file
```

I am running blast using arrays in parallel. I splitted my fasta file to several with $SGE_TASK_ID being a number. Is it possible to save the output of all $SGE_TASK_ID in one single file? How? Besauce all the times it overrides it...

Answer (score 0):

I concatenated my many output files

```
cd $OUTDIR
cat *.blast > $OUTDIR/single_output_file
```

If there are other ways, please, let me know. Thanks